# Should I make code conditional if fallacy of condition would make code unreachable

Tags: python, pep8

suppose I have the following code:

```py
def isIn(a:str, b:list[str]) -> str:
   yup = False
   for i in b:
      if i == a:
         return 'is'
         yup = True
   if not yup:
      return 'is not'
```

now, if line 7 is reached, `yup` must be false. According to the official Python style (perhaps PEP 8?), should I still make line 8 conditional, or should I just put it after the `for` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has very little to do with PEP8, but just with programming logic.

In your code, since you `return` a value before even setting `yup` to `True`, `yup` will always be `False` in your entire function. So, checking if it is `False` is superfluous. In fact, this does the exact same:

```
def is_in(a: str, b: list[str]) -> str:
    for i in b:
        if i == a:
            return 'is'
    return 'is not'
```

Something that *is* a PEP8 issue is that you were using different indent depths, please don't. Also, whitespace is expected after the colon following a function parameter before the type hint. And naming functions and variables, you should stay away from capitals - `isIn` is OK but `is_in` is more Pythonic.

Note that your function as it currently is, only restricts an operator that Python has already (in that your type hints will cause warnings if the types don't match):

```
# this is how you'd use your function:
if is_in('word', ['a', 'word', 'or', 'four']) == 'is':
    print('it is')

# but you could just:
if 'word' in ['a', 'word', 'or', 'four']:
    print('it is')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `yup`. You either return from inside the loop, or the loop completes and you return `'is not'`.

```
def isIn(a:str, b:list[str]) -> str:
   for i in b:
      if i == a:
         return 'is'
   return 'is not'
```

But all you are doing is reimplementing the `in` operator:

```
def isIn(a: str, b: list[str]) -> str:
    return 'is' if a in b else 'is not'
```